# Redux Observable ( Epic ) - concat two promises before returning action

Tags: redux, rxjs5, redux-observable

I'm stuck trying to accomplish the following. In my React app, I am using redux-observable Epics.

I have two promises, one which needs to wait for the second, before it fires.

```
import { map, mergeMap, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';
.....

    const promise1 = Auth.getCredentials().then( credentials => {
        return credentials
    }

    const promise2 = ( credentials ) => {
         return doQuery(credentials, someData).then(function(data) {
                   // return success
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    // reject error
                });
    }
```

So promise 2 needs the credentials from promise1, I am having a hard time knowing how to use observable/fromPromise etc to 'chaing' these items together so that the result of ends up either in the 'map' or 'catchError' result
In my Epic, i have something like this:

```
const searchEpic: Epic<RootAction, RootState> =
    (action$, store) => action$.ofType(DO_QUERY)
        .mergeMap(({payload}) => {

               ???????? - this is where Im stuck 


               const $stream = RESULT_OF_PROMISES.pipe(
                    map((response) => {
                        return actionCreators.success(..)
                    },
                    catchError(e => {
                        return of(actionCreators.failure(..));
                    }
                )));


            return $stream
        });
```

Thank you!

Comment: `promise1.then(promise2)` doesn't work?

Comment: @Oblosys.  Thanks ! Haha, well apparently I was overthinking this.  You got me on the right track. it was basically fromPromise(promise1.then(promise2)).pipe( map.....   I actually didn't think that would work, but it did just fine : )